# Can't get the Scala tools to work in Odersky's Coursera course

Tags: eclipse, scala, ide, ubuntu-12.04

In [Odersky's scala course](https://class.coursera.org/progfun-2012-001/wiki/view?page=ToolsSetup) I'm trying to run the tools setup.

[image: my eclipse doesn't look like their eclipse]

Where I'm supposed to have `Run As > 2. Scala Application` I only have `Run As > Run Configurations`.

What do I need to do to make my screen work like the example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer, due to [Carston Krebbs](https://www.coursera.org/user/i/d88f282fde9c1776a11970051de59b34), was to delete the line between

```
package greeter


object hello extends App {
```

. Thanks to the others who tried an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I am also doing this course. What I see be me (eclipse downloaded from course web site) is that I can use "Run As Scala Application" only on Scala objects which calls main method (the metod body is in the object).

There is a forum specialy for this course. Ask this question there.

Comment: I asked the question there as well but I think it go unnoticed and  homework is due in 1.5 dyas.

Answer (score 1):

try wrapping the println inside a main method.

```
def main(args: Array[String]) {
  println("Hello, world!")
}
```

I had this similar problem and this is how i solved it.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a problem with the course material actually

The first lesson goes on to say...

In order to make the object executable it has to extend the type App. Change the object definition to the following:

```
object Main extends App {
  println(Lists.max(List(1,3,2)))
}
```

So in this case, extend App and you should be able to run it

Answer (score 0):

Since i often had problems with eclipse i switched to intellij.

Install [intellij](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) and the intellij scala plugin.

Get the sbt plugin [sbt-idea](https://github.com/mpeltonen/sbt-idea).

Startup sbt and type `gen-idea`.

Open the idea project and start programming.

Comment: Or even without sbt-idea: "New Project" > "Import project from external model" (To submit your solution, simply use sbt from a Terminal/CLI).

Answer (score 0):

Start eclipse with the `-clean` option. That will clear certain caches and most likely fix your issues.

Answer (score 0):

Save what you have. Exit and re-open Eclipse.
- odersky student